# How can I get my actual bytes that I used to make a big byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a method which makes one byte array as per below format.

- First it gets avroBytes.
- Then it snappy compresses it.
- Then it makes another byte array with particular format as shown below.

Below is the method:

```
  public static byte[] serialize(final Record record, final int clientId,
      final Map<String, String> holderMap) throws IOException {
    byte[] avroBytes = getAvroBytes(holderMap, record);
    byte[] snappyCompressed = Snappy.compress(avroBytes);

    int size = (2+8+4) + snappyCompressed.length;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    buffer.putShort((short) clientId);
    buffer.putLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
    buffer.putInt(snappyCompressed.length);
    buffer.put(snappyCompressed);
    buffer.rewind();

    byte[] bytesToStore = new byte[size];
    buffer.get(bytesToStore);

    return bytesToStore;
  }
```

Now I want to get my actual `avroBytes` once I have `bytesToStore`

```
byte[] bytesToStore = serialize(......);
// now how can I get actual `avroBytes` using bytesToStore?
```

Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Split your method in two methods: one that generates and returns the avroBytes, the second one which takes them as argument to generate bytesToStore.

Comment: In my case, at the end of the program once I have `bytesToStore` then I need to get my avroBytes back for some debugging purpose. This is just one time exercise so that's why i wanted to do some verification.

Comment: There's always `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesToStore, 2 + 8 + 4, bytesToStore.length)`.  But I suspect you would be better off returning the ByteBuffer instead of a byte array.

Comment: or change `serialize` to return a custom object that gives you access to all the required data. Like a simple pojo consisting of bytesToStore & avroBytes.

Comment: @VGR what does `Arrays.copyOfRange` will do here?

Comment: If it's for debugging purpose, then use your debugger, put a breakpoint after the computation of avroBytes, and inspect its value.

Comment: @david http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-

Comment: I mean, let's assume given a `bytesToStore` byte array, I want to get my actual avroBytes byte array back.

Comment: @VGR so that means output of `Arrays.copyOfRange` will be a byte array which will be `snappyCompressed ` so now I can snappy uncompressed it to get my actual `avroBytes` back? Am I right?

Comment: As the documentation says, it just returns a new array containing the bytes from index 14 to the end.  The method has no knowledge of the format or meaning of those bytes.

Comment: yup got it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, the compressed version starts at `bytesToStore[14]`, so one simple, but not necessarily most efficient way would be to make a copy of the bytes from that location, and call `Snappy.uncompress(bytes)`.

Something like this:

```
public static int HEADER_SIZE = 2 + 8 + 4;

public static byte[] extractAvroBytes(byte[] bytesToStore) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesToStore, HEADER_SIZE, bytesToStore.length);
    return Snappy.uncompress(bytes);
}
```

I haven't tested this, so some tweaking may be required.

Depending on the Java interface to snappy that you are using, there may be methods available to decompress data directly from the serialized bytes without making an intermediate copy.

Comment: Yeah I tested it based on VGR suggestion and it worked very well.

Comment: Can you help me with another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947887/deserialize-array-in-a-particular-format-to-get-map-from-it) of mine which is also on byte array and byte buffer?

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like there is already a method that returns  `avroBytes`, e.g.:

`byte[] avroBytes = getAvroBytes(holderMap, record);`

This method needs `holderMap` and `record` as aguments, and looking at the code where `serialize` is called, you already have those two values. So, if possible, you can call `getAvroBytes` before calling  `serialize` and pass it as an argument to `serialize` method.